# Finding the transfer function symbolically in Matlab

Tags: function, matlab, variables, transfer

The following Matlab script uses functions such as tf to find the transfer function of a system and these functions require numeric inputs, so making a modification such as defining G1, G2, G3, H1, H2, and H3 as symbolic variables causes an error message. Is there another way to modify the code to find the transfer function in terms of G1, G2, G3, H1, H2, and H3 without having to initialize them?

```
G1=tf(1,[1 1]);
G2=G1;G3=G1;
H1=tf(1,[1 0]);
H2=H1;H3=H1;
System=append(G1,G2,G3,H1,H2,H3);
input=1;output=3;
Q= [1 -4 0 0 0; ...
2 1 -5 0 0;...
3 2 1 -5 -6;...
4 2 0 0 0;...
5 2 0 0 0;...
6 3 0 0 0];
T=connect(System,...
Q,input,output);
T=tf(T);T=minreal(T)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I grasp what you're ultimately looking for. If you want to convert your final transfer function `T` to symbol representation, then you can use `tfdata` and `poly2sym`. If you want to know the symbolic relationship of `G1`, `G2`, etc. to `T`, then I think you are stuck working with the symbolic toolbox the whole way through.

Comment: In the code above I had to initialize the transfer functions. I am looking for a way that I can find represent them symbolically and get a symbolic output for the transfer function between two nodes, such as G1*G2 instead of 1/(s+1)^2.